# Proving that $\lim y_i=\lim x_i$

Tags: real-analysis

Let $P_{ij}$, where $P_{ij}$ is a real number and $i, j$ natural number, allow the three statements to hold:

- $P_{ij}\ge 0$ for all $i, j$
- $\lim_{i\to\infty}P_{ij}=0$ for all $j$
- $\sum_{j=1}^i P_{ij}$ =1 for all $i$

Let $(x_j)$ be a convergent sequence and let a sequence $(y_i)$ be defined by

$y_i=\sum_{j=1}^i P_{ij}x_j$

Prove $(y_i)$ is a convergent sequence, and prove $\lim y_i=\lim x_i$

I don't really know how to approach the problem, thanks in advance

Comment: The $n$ made all the difference. The third bullet looks fine now. You still to make 1 more edit: $y_i=\sum_{j=1}^i P_{ij}x_j$.

Comment: @KimJongUn thanks, sometimes typing here is tedious to get it all right, mistakes fly under the radar all the time

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Firstly, we may assume that $\lim x_i=0$. We may assume that $|x_i|<M$ holds.

Fix arbitrary $\epsilon>0$, there exists $N$ such that $|x_i|<\epsilon $ for all $i>N$.

Then you see that

\begin{align*}
|y_i|\leq {}&\sum_{j=1}^i P_{ij}|x_j|\\
={}&\sum_{j\leq N} P_{ij}|x_j| +\sum_{j> N} P_{ij}|x_j|\\
<{}&\sum_{j\leq N} P_{ij}M +\sum_{j> N} P_{ij}\epsilon\\
\leq{}&\sum_{j\leq N} P_{ij}M +\epsilon
\end{align*}

Note that $\lim_i\sum_{j\leq N} P_{ij}M=0$ since it is a finite sum.

That means there exist $N'$ such that $|y_i|<2\epsilon$ for $i>N'$.

QED

Comment: What of if $\lim x_{i}\ne 0$?

Comment: consider the new sequence $x_i-\lim x_i$ instead of $x_i$

Comment: Why is the finite sum with M in it equal to 0?  I don't see where this is coming from, it's probably just me

Comment: since the limit of $P_ij$ is 0.